# Is there any institution that has translated or is translating the Bible to Indian languages from Textus Receptus?

Tags: bible, bible-translation

I know there is one Hindi translation by William Carey but that is such an old translation that the Hindi used in that is no longer spoken in India.

Comment: The Trinitarian Bible Society use Textus Receptus for all their translations. They issued a new Nepali translation in 2011, but I don't know if  any other Indian languages, apart from Nepali have one..http://www.tbsbibles.org/uk/news/translation

Comment: A link to a pdf file of the gospel of John from that Nepali translation is here: https://tbsbibles.site-ym.com/news/333203/TBS-Nepali-Scriptures.htm

Answer (score 3):

There is a relatively recent Nepali translation by the Trinitarian Bible society, as described in this [news item](https://www.tbsbibles.org/news/333203/TBS-Nepali-Scriptures.htm). The gospel of John can be downloaded from [here](http://c.ymcdn.com/sites/www.tbsbibles.org/resource/collection/10B4B62B-75A3-4AA9-8252-E0C00A2DE046/%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8B-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0.pdf) (pdf). Thanks to davidlol for the link.

In Hindi, I could only find this old 1851 Bible described on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Reformed/comments/6vhnib/is_there_any_institution_that_has_translated_or/),  translated the Bible from the Textus Receptus in 1851 by William Carey and others.

> The Presbyterian Mission Press published a complete Hindi translation in 1851 that used the received text for the NT. William Carey played a key role in its early development. You can download electronic versions from archive.org.

And indeed,[this page on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/holybibleinhindi00alla) has a Hindi Bible you can read or download.